# Starting Sublime Text from a C# application and passing the file to open as a parameters

Tags: c#, process, mono

I am trying to start subl in linux froma C# application with Mono using the following code:

```
Process rc;

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = editor;
startInfo.Arguments = targetFileName;

rc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

where targetFileName is the name of a file (created earlier in the application) to open in the editor which is subl.

The application opens subl OK, but the file is empty. It works properly on Windows using EmEditor as the editor, but not on linux.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I discovered my error. When setting the targetfilename, I was not using the same name to save the file as I was in passing it to subl. Turns out that I did not have the TEMP environment variable set and there was no entry for the temp directory in my configuration file for the application. DUH!